# (ReactJS) How do you get the input value of an input of type date?

Tags: reactjs, date

I currently have

```
<input type="date" onChange={(input) => { _this.setState({startDate: input})}}/>
```

No matter what I've been changing around (the onChange part to ref etc etc), startDate shows up as undefined when I console.log my state. I've even changed `startDate:input` to `startDate:input.value` and it still hasn't worked.

I tried using many react libraries such as react-datepicker and etc. So far they haven't really been working out for me(We have a ton of CSS and their CSS is messed up due to that issue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what `_this` is.

I'd recommend checking out the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) on `input` events to get an idea of what they are / how to intercept them.

See below for a working example.

```
<input type="date" onChange={(event) => this.setState({startDate: event.target.value})}/>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. And Usually I set var _this = this; just for safe keeping and always use _this to make sure im calling the main Class

Comment: How can we get a value of Airbnb calendar if it's a SingleDatePicker?