# How to get value of JSX Input field to Javascript date object and then insert it to mysql YYYY-MM-DD format?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, reactjs

I need to get the picked value of input type= "date" to a Javascript Date object and format it, then use Insert Into Table for MySQL. How?

I need to get the picked date value from input to use with this function, and after that I need a function that inserts that picked value to MySQL. I don't know how to do those steps.. I am making a rental system, so I will have two inputs "startdate" "enddate" that need to be converted for inserting to database.

This is a function I found that formats a date:

```
(function() {
    Date.prototype.toYMD = Date_toYMD;
    function Date_toYMD() {
        var year, month, day;
        year = String(this.getFullYear());
        month = String(this.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = String(this.getDate());
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you.

```
function getYYMMDD() {
   var now = new Date();     
   var mm = (now.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2,"0");
   var yyyy = now.getFullYear().toString();
   var dd =  now.getDate().toString().padStart(2,"0");
   var date = [yyyy, mm, dd].join("-");
   return date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do I use an <input "date" field to get date information so I can use this function?

Comment: @Bill Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763893/reactjs-how-do-you-get-the-input-value-of-an-input-of-type-date